# BigQuery Data Transfer Service Error 9

Tags: google-bigquery, double-click-advertising

I am getting the below error messaging within the BigQuery Data Transfer service. Has anyone else had any experience with the same error?

Thanks!

[BigQuery Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvNUn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BQ DTS Eng here.

This column was not yet supported in our schema, but we have adjusted the schema and your transfer should start working within a week without additional changes on your side.

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: (BQ DTS Eng here again)
To be precise, the rollout will be completed by end of next week.